# Ruby: update attribute of an object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pass-by-reference

I have these two classes in Ruby:

**Prod.rb**

```
class Prod
  attr_reader :code, :price
  def initialize code, price
    @code = code
    @price = price
  end
end
```

**Buy.rb**

```
class Buy
  def initialize()
    @items = []
  end

  def addToBasket item
    @items << item
  end

  def changePrice
      @items.each do |item|
        item.price = 0.00
      end
  end
end
```

When I am testing the app with the code below, I get this error pointing to the `item.price = 0.00` above:

```
test_1(MyTest): NoMethodError: undefined method 'price=' for #<Prod:0x24d76e8>
```

I can print the value of item.price but I cannot update it. Any ideas?

**MyTest.rb**

```
def setup
    @prod1 = Prod.new("1", 19.95)
  end

  def test_1
    b = Buy.new()
    b.addToBasket(@prod1)
    [...]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't have a `price=` method defined in class `Prod`. You only defined a getter with `attr_reader :code, :price`. If you to create both getter and setter, user `attr_accessor` in your `Prod` class:

```
class Prod
  attr_accessor :code, :price
  def initialize code, price
    @code = code
    @price = price
  end
end
```

You can learn more about getters and setters in ruby in my article: [Ruby for Admins: Objects](http://rubyforadmins.com/objects#instance-variables).